# Store a VarChar or JSON in mySQL

Tags: mysql, json, database

I am at a point in which while implementing a simple database schema I am attemtping to think ahead, and do things that would not hinder performance should te database grow larger.

The main object that will be manipulated within the application that will be using the database will be a JSON String. Now I am fully aware of the ability to store a JSON formatted string (JSONfs) within SQL as just a VARCHAR, but I recently learned that they have adopted the JSONfs type into their provided base types.

Now comes the question, the JSONfs will be manipulated, possibly heavily so, and I am unsure if this would cause issues while using the JSONfs type in MySQL. I am not sure if updates to the JSONfs that is populated and placed into the DB could be altered within simple mySQL commands, and honestly I would rather leave that task to the initial JSON parser/formatter due to the possible overcomplexity of the JSONfs that will be used.

Questions:

(1) Is the above statement of added complexity with trying to modify a string, specifically the JSONfs, within SQL more of an overhead causing situation than running an UPDATE, and just altering the data within that Column?

(2) Does the UPDATE process being called multiple times on a DB cause some type of bottleneck after a while if say, 25K UPDATES are done within a short amount of time? I hope the DB's can handle much more than those requests, but just a rough estimate of the possible read/writes to the system.

(3) Am i completely wrong in the manner that I believe mySQL to handle it's internal objects/DB Entries? If so could some enlightenment on this procedure be shed, as I am still in the process of creating the ER Model, and simple is better for now than overcomplicated, but long term is also something that I try and keep my head around.

Comment: Why is this question tagged with Microsoft SQL Server? MySQL is not "Mycrosoft SQL".

Comment: If you're investing heavily in JSON you may want to pick an RDBMS platform that supports it better. MySQL 5.7 has limited support for JSON, it's at least a first-class data type, but it's way behind others. [Postgres has considerable support for it](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-json.html) and if you're really doubling down on JSON, [MongoDB](http://mongodb.org) might be worth considering. You'll have to do a lot of testing here to answer your questions. There's no silver bullet solution.

Comment: I know the big DBs are starting to add support for arrays in their databases, but i still hate the idea of doing this. Databases and their tables are basically just arrays. So instead of storing an array in a column, I make a new table (or multiple tables) to store it. Doing this I don't have to parse the whole array to get a single item from it.

Comment: To address @tadman the rest of the project relies heavily on SQL, trust me due to the use of nodejs I really want to go with Mongo, but need fast integration with Go-Lang, and also C/C++, and Python for another aspect of the project. 2 of the three main languages that I'll be using recommend SQL for their use, but Mongo is still an option.

Comment: For @CptMisery, the reason for not doing this outright is that there will not be a static implementation for the object itself, and JSON allows for easier exclusion than just carpet bombing a SQL Table with NULL's. And to tadman again the SQL was suggested, and I blindly clicked on it. Should've read a bit more.

Comment: I've decided that as a proof of concept, I'll end up writing the DB out in Mongo... Everythig will be external functions so they will allow for an easy shift to mySQL if the need should arise, only thing that could be an issue wihtin that end would be the creation of the Mongo->mySQL (Or whatever end DBMS is decided on, may still go with SQL due to the seemingly lacking security of Mongo, and user sensitive material, but as a proof of concept this point is sideline-able. ) Will not close the question completely because I am still somewhat interested in the answer to the above questions though.

Comment: Remember you can mix SQL and MongoDB if you want. I've found Postgres to be a pretty good compromise, it's an RDBMS that understands JSON. In many cases you can make Postgres operate like MongoDB as a document store and still have all your usual relational data control.